# How to create multiple environments in AWS Account?

Tags: amazon-web-services

I like to create multiple environments in AWS Account rather than multiple accounts, how can this be done?

Use-case for this is each environment can have its own stack, so each environment will have DynamoDB, Lambda, services etc.

I could not find any documentation on how to create multiple environments in AWS Account

Comment: You can think of an account as an environment, and multiple accounts is best practice. There’s no cost for an account itself so out of curiosity, why not use multiple accounts? As for environments, there are many ways to do it. If not using a dedicated account, my preferred method would be to adopt a naming convention for resources: `my-lambda-dev` `my-lambda-prod` etc. and then limit access to them via roles.

Comment: You can use Roles for managing access , Once you define the roles with policies you can add these to users in same account using Trust policy.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_roles_use_switch-role-console.html?icmpid=docs_iam_console